max_concurrency_level snowflake warehouse parameter
I have been testing our dashboard load with Large warehouse with different values of max_concurrency_level, last week I set the value to 24 (April last week), May first week I increased the value to 32.
For the same load, queuing has increased with 32 concurrency_level value.
Nothing has changed in queries or their schedules. Anybody has seen this sort of behavior?


What is it that you are trying to achieve here and what types of queries are being executed?  It is not common to modify this value away from its default value of 8.  The value limits the maximum number of queries, but doesn't guarantee that number of queries CAN be executed concurrently.  A single query could completely saturate a warehouse.  I would highly recommend that you set this value back to the default of 8 and instead multi-cluster your warehouse.  This avoids queueing for the most part and things will run better/faster.

We use Standard edition, can't use multi-cluster feature. Queries are daily aggregate batches, when I increased the parameter from 8 to 24 performance slightly improved, but with 32 it reduced significantly. Nothing changed in the queries or data loads

For the queries that are running, are they taking longer to run (ignoring the queue time)?  That's likely what I'd expect to see.  I would recommend trying to spread out your load across multiple warehouses, rather than messing with the concurrency setting.
